# selectedSegmentIndex not updating UISegmentControl

Tags: iphone, uisegmentedcontrol

In my viewDidLoad, I'm retrieving user preferences and updating the settings tab. It is working for editSelection (see code) but the other

```
  NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

  BOOL editSelection = [userDefaults boolForKey:@"editToggleSwitch"];
  editingToggle.selectedSegmentIndex  = editSelection; // this is working!

  bToggle.selectedSegmentIndex = [[userDefaults objectForKey:@"bSegment"] intValue];
```

In the view, the editingToggle segment is displaying correctly but bToggle is always at 0? NSLog shows that the data was saved and retrieved correctly. I've even set

```
 bToggle.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
```

but it still does not reflect correctly in the view? Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just guessing: bToggle not wired up in Interface Builder?

Comment: Nikolai you are brilliant! I hooked up the Value Changed but forgot the Referencing outlet - Dooh!!!!

Answer (score 2):

One other gotcha. You can't put the initialization code for the segmented controls in the init because the view is not on the screen yet. I put it in viewDidLoad and it works fine now.